# Issues in installing data migration tool to migrate from Magento 1.9.0.1 to Magento 2.1.0

Tags: magento-1.9, database, magento-2.1, magento2-migration-tool

I have installed Magento 2.1.0, I tried [Install the Data Migration Tool](https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/blob/master/README.md) , I tried **Install the tool from GitHub** by using

```
composer config repositories.data-migration-tool git https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool
composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.1.0
```

On running 2nd command, I am getting,

[image]
what am I missing? I am using OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 , php 5.6.10 and MySQL 5.6.25

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you did forget to setup the public and private key portions to use with the magento repository for composer to work.

Look here, they explain it well.
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html

You need to authenticate as a member of magento marketplace.

Comment: have done this, will try again,